# weird error that i cant solve in model class of json

Tags: json, flutter, dart, model

it says "Missing type arguments for map literal." . s

```
 Map<String, dynamic> toJsonAdd() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'email': email,
    };
  }
}
```

please help me with complete code, thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you please add the complete JSON over here so that we can check the Model?

Comment: is it because linter? maybe you need put some argument such as: `Map<String, dynamic> toJsonAdd() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'name': name,
      'email': email,
    };
  }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this sample,

```
class UserModel {
  String id;
  String name;
  String email;

  UserModel({this.id, this.name, this.email});

  UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    email = json['email'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['email'] = this.email;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Your code doesn't look wrong. Maybe you can restart vscode